# Error when sending mail with cakephp

Tags: email, cakephp

I'm now using CakePHP since a while, and I wanted to use the Email component.
But I'm having trouble with it.

Indeed, when I try to send an email, i get a :

Could not send email.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Well... But, why ? ^^

Here is my Controller:

```
$this->Email->from = 'Email<my.email@myHost.fr>';
$this->Email->to = 'Another.Email@AnotherHost.com';
$this->Email->subject = 'This is the email Subject';
if ($this->Email->send('This is the email message'))
    $this->set('success', 'Email successfully sent !');
```

And my Email.php in app/Config:

```
public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('contact@myHost.fr' => 'myHost'),
    'host' => '192.168.10.50',
    'port' => 25,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false,
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
```

I also wanted to know if Cake is using a binary to send email like 'sendmail' or 'mail', because on my linux server, these binaries are not install.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The `EmailComponent` has been deprecated since CakePHP 2.x and was replaced with the [CakeEmail library class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html) instead. I believe that only `CakeEmail` bothers to read your config from `app/Config/Email.php`, the `EmailComponent` took it's options as a property (`smtpOptions`) instead.

It's quite easy to migrate to the new `CakeEmail` component, above your controller class definition, just add:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

And then in your controller, replace your current code with this:

```
// In the top of your controller, initialize the component variable first.
private $__Email;

// In your action...
$this->__Email = new CakeEmail();
$this->__Email->from('my.email@myHost.fr')
    ->to('email@AnotherHost.com')
    ->subject('This is the email Subject')
    ->send('This is the email message');

$this->set('success', 'Email successfully sent !');
```

As for your second question, yes you will need to install an MTA (Mail Transport Agent) like sendmail on the server you are using to send the mail. Under water, CakeEmail uses PHP's `mail()` method, that uses whatever you have set as `sendmail_path` in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: Only i wouldn't use private stuff here in a framework context.

Comment: @mark Anything from outside the current controller does not have to access the component's properties. So it makes sense to set it to private in such cases, there's no need to use a broad scope.

Comment: rubbish. framework = you can always extend an existing controller/component (even from plugins) etc. using protected is not about a broad scope. either make it public or protected (= the class or its subclasses). I personally dont think "private" should ever be used once in such a project. there is absolutely no need for it whatsoever.

Comment: In this case `$this->_Email` (protected) should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for security reasons, I could not install any others binaries like mail, sendmail or whatever, so I cannot use the Email function :(

Comment: If there is no MTA or remote SMTP server available to you whatsoever, mailing would indeed become an impossibility.

Comment: I am using the same code but not able to receive mail.Try debugging but no success.

Answer (score 0):

1) Configure your app/config/email.php:

```
public $gmail = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'your qmail username@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
    );
```

2) Load email component on top of controller

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

3) Send email

```
    public function send_email(){
            $Email = new CakeEmail();
            $Email->config('gmail');
            $Email->from('from@gmail.com');
            $Email->to('to@gmail.com');  
            $Email->subject('Expire Date Information ');
            $Email->emailFormat('html');
            $Email->send();
    }
```